In Nuxt.js how to add a username dynamically to a URL like http://localhost:3001/profile & http://localhost:3001/profile/@user

pages/profile.vue
pages/_username.vue

To handle both URLs—http://localhost:3001/profile (generic profile route) and http://localhost:3001/profile/@user (dynamic username route)—in Nuxt.js

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To do that you need to create the next folder structure
-| pages/
---| profile/
-----| index.vue
-----| [usernane].vue

and then in your component you can get the username with
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.params.username)
</script>


Reference: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing
